# how can I get a set of prices based on a set of specific dates in pandas and datareader in python

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-datareader

i'm a beginner at pandas and python and i'm trying to anlyze stock data.
I got dividend data I want with the date of the dividend. now I want to go back 10 days and see the price in that date. I sucessuflly added the new colunm but can't add the price based on the new colunm

```
            action     value   Date -10 Days   price -10 days
2020-07-16  DIVIDEND    0.0900  2020-07-06  ###
2020-04-16  DIVIDEND    0.1870  2020-04-06  ###
2020-01-16  DIVIDEND    0.1870  2020-01-06  ###
```

```
import datetime
import pandas_datareader as pdr
from pandas_datareader import data

stc = data.DataReader('4339.SR', 'yahoo-actions')
price10 = pdr.get_data_yahoo('4339.SR')
end_date = stc.index + datetime.timedelta(days=-10)
stc['Date -10 Days'] = end_date
stc['price -10 days'] = '###'
stc
```

what should I do to insert the new price for 2020-07-06 and then 2020-04-06....etc

many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'df.merge' is used to find the left join of the data frame with the closing price.

```
stc.merge(price10[['Close']], left_on='Date -10 Days', right_index=True, how='left')

    action  value   Date -10 Days   Close
2020-07-16  DIVIDEND    0.0900  2020-07-06  9.49
2020-04-16  DIVIDEND    0.1870  2020-04-06  10.00
2020-01-16  DIVIDEND    0.1870  2020-01-06  10.58
2019-10-14  DIVIDEND    0.1870  2019-10-04  NaN
2019-07-16  DIVIDEND    0.1870  2019-07-06  NaN
2019-04-16  DIVIDEND    0.1870  2019-04-06  NaN
2019-01-01  DIVIDEND    0.1870  2018-12-22  NaN
2018-12-30  DIVIDEND    0.1870  2018-12-20  8.20
2018-10-01  DIVIDEND    0.1810  2018-09-21  NaN
2018-09-27  DIVIDEND    0.1810  2018-09-17  8.02
2018-06-27  DIVIDEND    0.1810  2018-06-17  8.02
2018-03-28  DIVIDEND    0.1023  2018-03-18  NaN
```